# Skype animation not working on my ubuntu machine

Tags: 12.04, skype

On my system's skype animation is not working on its symbolys. please help how to enable animation on skype

Comment: I am not getting the question. What skype animation? I never missed or noticed an animation in Skype indicator, it just shows of my status. Please be more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Skype, choose Options->Chat and select "Show animated emoticons".

Then click apply.

Answer (score 1):

I think you means Animated Emoticons. To enable emoticons in Skype :-

**Goto > Tools > IM/SMS section > IM Appearance**

Check/Uncheck the box to enable or disable animated emoticons.